# Remove useless dependencies in Hive UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I'm writing a set of User Defined Functions (UDF) for Hive in a Java Maven project.

I'm using maven assembly plugin to generate an uber-jar. However, I'm also including tons of dependencies I'm sure hive already has on it's classpath, SLF4j for instance.

Is there a simple way (tool) to know what's already on the hive classpath ? I'm using HDP 2.2 from Horton Works

Answer (score 1):

**dependency:analyze** in Maven Dependency Plugin will help.

> `dependency:analyze` analyzes the dependencies of this project and
>   determines which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused
>   and declared.
>
> [dependency:analyze](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html)

**dependency:tree** is another thing that might help. This has tools to allow you to do the analysis yourself.

> > `dependency:tree` displays the dependency tree for this project.
>
> [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo)

Comment: that's useful, and part of the solution. However I already know about those tools, so the addition would be to have a correct way to know what's already on the hive classpath. For instance, slf4j jars could already be on the hive classpath, but in a different version.

Answer (score -1):

The Query to get a list of all jars that are included in the ClassPath of Hive is:

```
hive> list jars;
```

The output will look like

```
file:/usr/local/…..*.jar
/usr/local/…..*.jar
```

The jar location with file: prefix is the one which was available in the ClassPath by default. The others were added explicitly by users using the add jar command.

Comment: nope, it isn't. I believe this command only lists jars that were explicitly added using `ADD JAR [...]` (at least in my case, it does).